# Minimize a function using the reselts from NDSolve

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I get some results `z1` from an equation

```
    s1 = y''[x] + Sin[y[x]] y[x];
    sol1 = NDSolve[{s1 == 0, y[0] == 1, y'[0] == 0}, y, {x, 0, 30}];
    sy[x_] = {y[x]} /. s;
    z1 = Table[Take[sy[x]], {x, 5, 30, 5}]
{{{-4.56095}}, {{0.999889}}, {{-4.55976}}, {{0.999555}},{{-4.55738}}, {{0.998999}}}
```

Now a new equation s2 contains `a` and `b`

```
    s2 = a*y2''[x] + b*Sin[y2[x]] y2[x]
```

The results `z2` should be solved using the same method.

```
    sol2 = NDSolve[{s2 == 0, y2[0] == 1, y2'[0] == 0}, y2, {x, 0, 30}];
    sy2[x_] = {y2[x]} /. s;
    z2 = Table[Take[sy2[x]], {x, 5, 30, 5}]
```

Then I want to minimize `(z1-z2).(z1-z2)` and find `a` and `b`

```
    Nminimize[(z1 - z2).(z1 - z2), {a, b}]
```

I know my codes can't work, but I'm trying to express thought. I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2):

Try (I simplified your code a little bit)

```
s1 = y''[x] + Sin[y[x]] y[x];
y1 = NDSolveValue[{s1 == 0, y[0] == 1, y'[0] == 0}, y, {x, 0, 30}];
(*y1[x] is the solution of ode s1 *)

s2 = a*y2''[x] + b*Sin[y2[x]] y2[x]
Y2 = ParametricNDSolveValue[{s2 == 0, y2[0] == 1, y2'[0] == 0},y2, {x, 0, 30}, {a, b}];
(*Y2[a,b][x] is the parametric(!) solution of ode s2*)
```

Minimization

```
NMinimize[Sum[ (y1[x] - Y2[a, b][x])^2 , {x, 5, 30, 5}], {a, b}]
(*{4.06908*10^-13, {a -> 0.980316, b -> 0.986701}}*)
```

To get the expected result `{a->1,b->1}` you should increase the WorkingPrecision inside `NDSolve`!

Comment: Thank you.But When I try to run a complicated case, I meet another problem, 
      `z2 = Table[Take[First[invysol], {Nn + 1, 2 Nn}].u2n[L/2], {t, 5, 20, 1}]
Take::normal: Nonatomic expression expected at position 1 in Take[1,{6,10}].
Take::normal: Nonatomic expression expected at position 1 in Take[1,{6,10}].
Take::normal: Nonatomic expression expected at position 1 in Take[1,{6,10}].
General::stop: Further output of Take::normal will be suppressed during this calculation.` 'invysol' is the solution of parametric function. and 'z2' is the element I want to take from `invysol`

Comment: It seems I can't use `Take` in the parametric function. How to solve this problem? Thank you again @Ulrich Neumann

Comment: Usually `Take` is applied to list(first argument), I don't understand what you intend to do.